# Magento with Nginx - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: magento2, nginx

I installed Magento2 trough Composer. I'm running a OS - Ubuntu16.04 with Nginx + MariaDb + php7. Database 'cb100' is already created in MariaDb;

When I type the url cb100.com I dont have any error. I'm just being redirected to cb100.com/setup/. I have a white page and a Magento favicon in the tab.

So I assume that something is working good, and something don't.

When I check my Nginx Log file this is what I have:

```
could not find named location "@handler", client: 127.0.0.1, server:
cb100.com, request: "POST /setup/index.php/session/prolong HTTP/1.1",
host: "cb100.com", referrer: "http://cb100.com/setup/"
```

I have no more clues.

Any missed configuration to Nginx ?

Note: NginX uses www-data group to run files inside the server. So I sit all files and folders inside bc100.com/ to be at the same group.

```
chown -R ila:www-data /cb100.com.
```

Comment: could not find named location "@handler", client: 127.0.0.1, server:

Comment: This a part of the yorsite.com/setup/index.php code.

Comment: looks like magento was only downloaded , not installed, and when redirected to setup/ nginx could not find the named location `@handler`